# What is wrong with this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting an error on this array. Array is:

```
    $array = array(
     ['parkingMode'] => array(
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 124
        [2] => 266
     ),
     ['owlMode'] => array(
        [0] => 124
        [1] => 129
        [2] => 266
     )
  );
```

how could be this correct?

> UPDATE:

Now I extend my question. Suppose I have an empty array like

```
`$newArray = array("parkingMode"=>array(),
                    "owlMode"=>array()
);
```

And what I am doing is pushing elements inside a foreach loop like,

```
foreach($devices as $k => $v) {
        $dev = $redis->hGetAll($v);
        //print_r($dev);
            if(array_key_exists('owlMode', $dev)){
                if($dev['owlMode'] =='on'){
                    array_push($newArray["parkingMode"], $k);
                }
            }

            if(array_key_exists('parkingMode', $dev)){
                if($dev['parkingMode'] =='on'){
                    array_push($newArray["owlMode"], $k);
                }
            }
    }

//print_r($newArray);
```

Then why this is giving me result like array in the format:

```
$array = array(
     ['parkingMode'] => array(
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 124
        [2] => 266
     ),
     ['owlMode'] => array(
        [0] => 124
        [1] => 129
        [2] => 266
     )
  );
```

`

Comment: `print_r` shows data in human readable form. This is not correct form to define array in php. For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: so you want to say that, the array generated is correct?

Comment: Right. Array is correct but not in form to be defined in PHP directly.

Comment: Okay @LovepreetSingh

Answer (score 5):

Elements in array should be separated by comma`,`. This is correct format:

```
$array = array(
    'parkingMode' => array(
        0 => 123,
        1 => 124,
        2 => 266
    ),
    'owlMode' => array(
        0 => 124,
        1 => 129,
        2 => 266
    )
);
```

Comment: yes @deadman, I have updated my question. Actually I was getting that array as a result of pushing selected elememts from another array in foreach.

Answer (score 1):

You should create associate array.In an associative array, the keys assigned to values can be arbitrary and user defined strings.

```
array(
     "parkingMode" => array(
        [0] => 123,
        [1] => 124,
        [2] => 266
    ), "owlMode" => array(
        [0] => 124,
        [1] => 129,
        [2] => 266
    ));
```